# I still Can't do a second commit in github

Tags: git, github

I read Gitbook it says

> ```
> git add file1
> git commit -m ' second commit'
> ```

i tried but not working
i need to update a file already present in the repo

what should i do?

Comment: You should provide more info.  Committing is a basic thing; i just did it twice without even thinking about it.  There's oddness in your setup that isn't reflected in the little info you've provided.

Comment: The editor has a `{}` button.  When you click it, it formats whatever's selected as code.  Alternatively, you could just indent it by 4 spaces.  :)

Comment: I am new to github so followed instructions as per in the page that shows after i created a new repo. it helped me add all the files in that folder to repo.
But what to do to do a second commit?

Comment: The second commit is no different from the first.  If a file's changed, you `git add` it, then you `git commit`.

Comment: @Sreevisakh cHao has enough rep to edit questions, they added four spaces in front of your two git lines which then tells stackoverflow to format the paragraph as code, when you ask a question there's a 'How to Format' section to the right that tells you how to format bold, italic, code etc

Comment: @chao where are the editor buttons?

Comment: @Sreevisakh: Right above the edit box.  See the **B** *I* etc?  Those are the editor buttons.

Comment: Where? above the small comment input field? I have no buttons?

Comment: The comment input field doesn't have them -- here, you just use Markdown to format stuff.  But check under your question; there should be an "edit" link.  If you click it, the question editor should pop up, and it should have buttons.  Really, though, the editor buttons just insert the right Markdown code to do stuff; you could do that yourself as well.

Comment: I ask page also i does'nt have buttons or edit link I only have three plain text boxes :(

Comment: Then your browser doesn't support JS, or for some reason is too paranoid to run it.  Oh well.  You can still format stuff; you just have to read the "how to format" info (that should be to the right of the edit box, for newbies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you say it isn't working? Does it output an error?

You should run those commands separately if you aren't already:

```
git add file1
git commit -m 'second commit'
```

if this doesn't produce any errors, then, assuming you're using the main 'master' branch run this to see it in github:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Comment: After executing the above (in the question) the files remain the change the same in the website does it take time to update in server?

Comment: It rejected says something about non-fast-forward updates are rejected to keep history

Comment: ah ok, you need to perform a `git pull origin master` so that you can grab any changes that are live before you push your own

Comment: if you run `git push origin master` now, it still doesn't work? Is that what you mean by failing?

Comment: Yes it worked now i can see the changes in the site thank a lot:)

Comment: Because people are being too hard on you. They don't feel that your question was very good, so they are voting you down. Sorry man, you can get your rep back up by providing helpful answers to other people's questions

Comment: I'll modify my original answer to include the pull command, in case it could help others.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question rather than voting it down 'Knowledge is meant to be shared' :p